# Request passport back while EEA residence card application is pending in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit, passport

I’m a EU resident who applied for UK resident as a EU citizen family member, I’ve done my biometrics and need to travel urgently, will my application be cancelled if I request for my passport?